# Create an error message for invalid input datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create an error message for an column

Suppose I  have a **column** - "`Employee Number`" with datatype **`varchar2`** in a table "`xyz`".

Now I'm importing a `.csv` or `.txt` file and there is also a column of "`employee number`" with datatype `varchar2` but I need only `number` data in this column...

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] and then try to edit your question by adding some more informations (table structure, code, sample data, …). As is, it's hard to give you a good answer

Comment: If you only want numbers in that column, define it as `number`. Do not store numbers in `varchar` columns

Comment: actually i want to create my own exception in which it will show my error message for invalid datatype for particular column.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you will import your data.

#### [Oracle `SQL*Loader`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm)

SQL loader can automatically check the input types for you, and raise appropriate error messages.

#### `PL/SQL`

If you choose to write your own import program in PL/SQL, then you can use [`Custom exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm) when you detect the case. It will look like follows:

```
 declare
    ex_custom EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( ex_custom, -20001 ); -- here you define a custom exception (by id number)
  begin
    -- here you import...
    if error_detected then
      raise_application_error( -20001, 'Wrong type ' );
    end;
  exception  -- then handle your exception
    when ex_custom
    then
      dbms_output.put_line( sqlerrm || 'error' );
 end;
SQL> /
ORA-20001: Wrong type error
```

I definitely advise you to choose the `sqlloader` solution in your case.

Comment: Then you may use the second part of the answer.